# jQuery Plugin 101

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new to all this, but after searching tutorials etc. I don't understand why this (and every single other JScript plugin I have pasted in my code*) isn't working.

*Both within the HTML itself and in a separate JS file...

```
<html>
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="test/css" href="stylesheet.css"/>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="imgContent"><div id="map"><script type="text/javascript">
$('#map').mobilymap({
    position: 'center', // map position after loading - 'X Y', 'center', 'top left', 'top right', 'bottom left', 'bottom right'
    popupClass: 'bubble',
    markerClass: 'point',
    popup: true, // show popup on marker click - true/false
    cookies: true, // remember last map position - true/false
    caption: true, // show caption - true/false
    setCenter: true, // sets the map view to the center on marker click
    navigation: true, // display buttons to pan in four directions
    navSpeed: 1000, // speed of panning map (higher value for slow panning)
    navBtnClass: 'navBtn',
    outsideButtons: false, // selector, only anchors eg. '.map_buttons a'
    onMarkerClick: function(){}, // call the function on marker click (popup must be disabled)
    onPopupClose: function(){}, // call the function after popup closing
    onMapLoad: function(){} // call the function after loading map
});
</script></div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

They haven't all looked like this and have tried them locally and on a server, but the recurring theme is that none of them are working (map plugins).

**Rest assured I know I'm missing something fundamental, I just don't know what it is!**

Comment: What does the Javascript console show?

Comment: Where do you load the plugin?

Comment: Javascript console shows: "Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'mobilymap' ".

Comment: When you say load the plugin, you mean like put "$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("#map").mobilityMap(); 
});" At the bottom of the script?

Comment: btw, JScript is not the same as JavaScript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You placed your `script` tag *within* the element you're trying to modify. Move the script tag **after** the `map` div:

```
<div class="imgContent">
    <div id="map">
    </div>
    <script src="path/to/your/scripts/mobilymap.js"></script>
    <script>
    $('#map').mobilymap({
        position: 'center', // map position after loading - 'X Y', 'center', 'top left', 'top right', 'bottom left', 'bottom right'
        popupClass: 'bubble',
        markerClass: 'point',
        popup: true, // show popup on marker click - true/false
        cookies: true, // remember last map position - true/false
        caption: true, // show caption - true/false
        setCenter: true, // sets the map view to the center on marker click
        navigation: true, // display buttons to pan in four directions
        navSpeed: 1000, // speed of panning map (higher value for slow panning)
        navBtnClass: 'navBtn',
        outsideButtons: false, // selector, only anchors eg. '.map_buttons a'
        onMarkerClick: function(){}, // call the function on marker click (popup must be disabled)
        onPopupClose: function(){}, // call the function after popup closing
        onMapLoad: function(){} // call the function after loading map
    });
    </script>
</div>
```

Your markup as shown also has no script reference to whatever the `mobilymap` plugin is, which is obviously a problem. It looks like an abandoned plugin, though there are a few projects that use the script that are open source, like this one: http://code.google.com/p/jqwicket/source/browse/trunk/jqwicket/src/main/java/com/google/code/jqwicket/ui/mobilymap/js/mobilymap.js?r=369

Comment: The comments were put in by the author of the plugin, not myself. Thanks a lot for your pointers

Comment: What do you mean about the script reference, the comments?

Comment: No. `mobilymap()` is not a function defined in the jQuery library, but a plugin built to leverage jQuery. So, to call that function, you have to load the source script for mobilymap first. That's why you see another `<script>` tag added to example above.

Comment: OK thanks for the info. Was looking at this solution also, but couldn't get it to work, despite the source scripts included. Literally copied it the exact same as it is on the screen with the source local... http://jvectormap.com/tutorials/getting-started/

Comment: That's an entirely different plugin, and I know that one works, since I've used it before. I suggest you either revamp your question, or ask a new one.